# find the Roots of this equation

Tags: quadratics

The roots of the equation $x^{4} -2x^{3} + x = 380$ are:

Though by trial and error one could solve the question, but I wanted to now if there is a particular method for solving the above equation ?

Comment: If you know the answers are integers, they will be about $\pm 380^{1/4}$ so try $\pm4, \pm5$, two of which are correct.  That would help with factoring

Comment: For a monic integer polynomial, the Rational Roots Test gives us that the only rational roots are in fact integer roots.  So what Henry suggests is essentially decisive in getting all roots, once the "known" factors are divided out.  That is, $x^4 - 2x^3 + x -380$ must be divisible by $x-5$, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

$x^4-2x^3+x^2-x^2+x-380=0$

$(x^2-x)^2-(x^2-x)-380=0$

$  p = x^2-x$

Now quadratic equation can be solved to get the answer

Answer (score 2):

HINT: note that $$x^4-2x^3+x-380=\left( x+4 \right)  \left( x-5 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-x+19 \right)$$

Comment: I know the answer, but how did you factorise it. I think there should be a proper way of getting its answer by adding and subtracting some terms of degree 2. Th is was a question in a particular exam from quadratic equations

Comment: use the rational root theorem

Comment: Can there be any other way of getting the answer